# Laravel many-to-many relationship - detach all and delete if nothing else attached

Tags: laravel, postgresql, eloquent

In laravel I got a many-to-many relation between nodes and users:

Nodes

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('nodes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id')->index();

            $table->string('syncState')->nullable();
            $table->integer('jsonRpcPort')->nullable();
            $table->string('addr')->unique()->index();
            $table->BigInteger('height')->nullable();
            $table->string('nodeId')->nullable();
            $table->string('publicKey')->nullable()->index();
            $table->integer('websocketPort')->nullable();
            $table->integer('relayMessageCount')->nullable();
            $table->integer('sversion')->nullable();
            $table->string('version')->nullable();

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

In Node-Model:

```
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->withPivot('hostname', 'label', 'notified_offline', 'notified_outdated', 'notified_stuck');
    }
```

Users

```
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');

            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->boolean('verified')->default(false);
            $table->string('password');

            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

In User-Model:

```
    public function nodes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Node')->withPivot('hostname', 'label', 'notified_offline', 'notified_outdated', 'notified_stuck');
    }
```

Node_user

```
    {
        Schema::create('node_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('node_id');

            $table->string('hostname')->nullable();
            $table->string('label')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('notified_offline')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('notified_outdated')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('notified_stuck')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')
            ->references('id')->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->foreign('node_id')
            ->references('id')->on('nodes')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
```

Now if I call `$user->nodes()->detach();` to detach all nodes from a user I also want that - if no other user is attached to - these node should also be removed from the database.

How do I archieve that? I'm using postgresql btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably easiest is to just do a check after calling the `detach()`.  Laravel is a little wishy-washy with observers for pivots, so if you have the `detach()` in just one method, perhaps something like the below code after the `detach()` action.

How about just checking the nodes in general that don't have a user, and then deleting them:

```
$nodesToDelete= Node::doesntHave('users')->pluck('id')->toArray();
Node::destroy($nodesToDelete);
```

If you only want to delete those that were just unattached, collect those 'to-be-detached' ids in an array before you detach them, and add to a whereIn clause in the above 1st line of code for only those nodes.